# Javascript: Check if the user is navigating away with a form submit or a simple link click

Tags: javascript, forms, navigation, onunload

I need to do remind the users something when they are leaving the page, and that can be handled with the window.onUnload event.
But I also need to check if the user is navigating away by submitting the form on the page, or by clicking the navigation links.
I could use the form's onSubmit event to set a flag, and then check against that flag in the window.onUnload event, but I am not sure which one fires first.

any ideas ?

Comment: Why don't you do a test and see what fires first?

Answer (score 5):

You actually want window.onbeforeunload

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var e = e || window.event;

  // For IE and Firefox
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Are You Sure?';
  }

  // For Safari
  return 'Are You Sure?';
};
```

Comment: I know it is a little old but [this source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) explains that this functionality is pre-Firefox 4.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the form.onSubmit event fires first so i can use a flag. I have checked this in Firefox and Safari only.

Comment: onsubmit will not fire if they refresh the page, click back, type a new url. To prevent loss of work, stick to onbeforeunload. By the way, for it to work properly, it must be done as Chad Grant described, not by addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

```
var isRefresh = true;
window.onunload = function () {
    alert('the page was ' + (isRefresh == false ? 'NOT ' : '') + 'refreshed');
}
$('a').live('click', function () { isRefresh = false; alert('a link was clicked'); });
$('form').bind('submit', function () { isRefresh = false; alert('form was submitted'); });
```

Based on [How to capture the browser window close event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event/1632004#1632004). I added the refresh logic.